# Captive Portal - Chillispot | OpenWrt vs DD-wrt

Tags: router, openwrt, dd-wrt, captivenetwork

I've been trying to configure a captive portal using DD-wrt and Open-wrt, with my own radius server and I've also tried to configure them using a CSP page (http://worldspot.net).

**DD-wrt**

My first try was with a TP-LINK WR841N (v7.) and DD-wrt using the web interface. In dd-wrt web interface there is an option in `Services -> HotsPot -> ChilliSpot`. Here I tried both configurations, using my own server data, and also tried with WorldSpot data, and my issue was the same in both cases:

When I enable Chillispot on the router, I don't get IP assigned, meaning I can't connect to the wifi/lan. It seems the problem is obviusly with the router and It's something like the Chillispot configuration is not working, or the changes are not"applied"

**Open-wrt**

After some hours trying to make work dd-wrt I think that maybe with open-wrt it was easier to configure, and here I found another problem. After updating my TP-LINK to Open-wrt I realized that I cannot access to the router via WEB, so I have to connect via telnet and ssh to install some packages and make some configurations.

I tried to install "luci" the package for the web gui and I found with some errors:
        - First It didn't find the package, and I have to change the `/etc/opkg.conf` file
        - Once I downloaded the package and try to access web I get error `uci_load: not found`
        - Once I fixed the uci package issue, I enable the uhttpd and start it, but when I try to connect via web I get another error "CGI didn't receive any response"

**Questions**

- Someone with more experience than me could point me wich of these softwares is better to have a spot system/captive portal ?
- It's possible that in **dd-wrt** case the configuration of chillispot wasn't applied to the router configuration ?
- For **open-wrt** anyone has same errors with the web interface ?
- I've been reading and it seems that it's possible to configurate ChilliSpot via `SSH` , but the tutorials I found were not very helpfull, anyone can point me to a good tutorial for this ?

I also have a `D-Link dir-615 H2` but it seems to be less compatible with open-wrt and dd-wrt than the TP-LINK.

I would be thankfull for any information that can put me in a good direction, thanks!

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I have a D-Link DIR-615 H2 and the latest version of DD-WRT doesn't include the Captive portal stuff it seems.

Comment: Sorry pal, I'm still waiting for some other to help us here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some months ago I found a very easy answer for this question about making a captive portal.

The best of this solution is that the router flashing part is very automatized and the **Captive Portal** configuration is made through a WEB UI very easy to understand and manage

*You may also connect through ssh to the router if some software customization is needed, like VLANS*

To use this solution your modem should be in this list(At the time the answer is wrote):

- Linksys: `WRT54G | WRT54GL | WRT54GS`
- MiniRouter: `MR3201A`
- FonSpot / Fonera (Atheros)
- Ubiquiti: `Bullet-M | Nano-M | Rocket-M | Airrouter | UniFi | Bullet/Nano/etc/{2/5}`

I used this method in several **Ubiquiti AirRouters** and now it just take me 5 minutes to configure a router for a HotSpot system using **FreeRadius**.

*I tried with **FreeRadius** installed in a **RaspBerry** in **LAN** and also into an **VPS** through **WAN***

The steps to flash any of the above routers are:

1. Download **coova-ap.jnlp** from [here](http://coova-ap.s3.amazonaws.com/desktop/coova-ap.jnlp)
2. Open the file with **Java Web Start**

> For Linux systems: **sudo javaws coova-ap.jnlp**

3. You have to click **Flash CoovaAP** and you will see a window like this where you should select your router model:

[image: Select your router model]

4. After the file is downloaded you will see the next window:

[image: Select your network device]

Here you should select your network device, usually eth0 (wired) is the best choice, anyways I **strongly** recommend to click **Save firmware to File** button to store a backup of the original firmware.

If youre using an Ubiquiti router, before clicking the **Start Flashing**
 you need to:

> .  If you re using a Ubiquiti device you should put it in TFTP mode by unplugging the POE ethernet cable, and reconnecting it while holding the reset button for 8 seconds. If this doesnt work, you may have to press it for 16 seconds. The LED lights now should flash alternately indicating TFTP mode.

Once you hit **Start Flashing** and the flash is done, the router will restart and we will be able to access the router using the same Coova software.

Now the **Configure CoovaAP** button should be clickable and we will see a very fancy interface to configure the router **Captive Portal**, we will be able to use different HotSpot configurations.

**If the button is not clickable make sure the CoovaAP IP is 192.168.1.1**

One of the guides that help me most to configure the router using CoovaAP software was [HotSpotSystem: Installation CoovaAP guide](http://www.hotspotsystem.com/installation-guide-coovaap-2-0)

On that tutorial you will have more information about some steps and the mainly configuration of the Captive Portal interface. I didn't add the HotSpot part because the question was about which was the best router configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to build a captive portal server:

**1.**

Regarding router compatibility I can only recommend **DD-WRT build 22118** or later (coovachilli based dd-wrt). 
Following versions are supported: mini_hotspot (broadcom_K26 non-nv60k , non-nv64k!), nokaid, standard, big or mega. Other versions (like mini or micro) don’t contain the hotspot module so they cannot be used for hotspot purposes.

Once you have a such build, you can start a simple Captive Portal with Chillispot.

All what you need is a FreeRadius server & Web Server.

**2.**

Using OptWARE

Here I used a router Asus RT N16, I've patched it with dd-wrt.v24-18024_NEWD-2_K2.6_mega.bin

The entire tutorial [is here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotelpbx/).